# Increase the value of a number in an element every XX seconds by 0.07

Tags: javascript

I've been using this script for a while now, but I can't seem to find a way to change the values into decimal and keep the script working...

Is there anyone that has more expertise on how to add 0.07 every XXX seconds. 
JS Fiddle or snippet is highly preferred! Thanks in advance!

```js
setInterval(function () {
     $('#badge').html(parseInt($('#badge').html()) + 1);
}, 100);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="badge">0</span>
```

Comment: [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat), [`Number.prototype.toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Parse the value to float](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) and if you need fixed digits in decimal places use [toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed).

```js
setInterval(function() {
  var data = parseFloat($('#badge').text()) + 0.07;
  $('#badge').html(data.toFixed(2));
}, 100);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="badge">0</span>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!
it worked just l hoped it should!

Answer (score 2):

Just use `Number()` function:

```js
setInterval(function () {
     $('#badge').html((Number($('#badge').html()) + 0.07).toFixed(2));
}, 100);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="badge">0</span>
```

`Number()`  allows you to use float and entire numbers, parsing them to a number if it's an string, similar to `parseInt()`+`parseFloat()` simultaneously.

I edit the code with the `toFixed(2)` to limit the number of decimals to 2

Answer (score 0):

Try the **window.setTimeout()** function:

```js
$().ready(function () {
  doIncrement();  
});

function doIncrement()
{
  window.setTimeout(function () {
    $("#badge").html((parseFloat($("#badge").html()) +0.07).toFixed(2));
    doIncrement();
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="badge">0</span>
```

## Explanation

You call the **doIncrement()** function recursively.

## Note

It is probably a good idea to include some form of flag so that it is not in an endless loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
setInterval(function () {
 $('#badge').html(parseFloat($('#badge').html()) + 0.07);,100);
```